# importing android library to eclipse downloaded from github

Tags: java, android, github

i want to download and edit and android library project from github and make jar file again and use it. i want to download and edit this project:

[ACRA project](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

i use eclipse. and my question is that how can i import this source code to eclipse and edit it? i download it and import it to eclipse but its not normal! it has 3 src folder and alot of folders like doc and ... and it has some errors... you know, i want only src folder with library configurations. it seems its a package for not use in development environment!
as you can see in the picture i uploaded, src package is inside some folders and... its not normal not? please help me

[image]

Comment: if your trying to make a crash reporter for your app 
just a suggestion that Crashlytics is very good crash reporter
https://www.crashlytics.com

Comment: try to use the jar file in your libs and follow this. https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup